# Unnecessary underline

Tags: html, css

Here is my [fiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/algeraranda/Lvh8n2z4/2/). Why is it that the last ul is affecting the paragraph on the left.

Here is an excerpt how formatted the html,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <title>Thanks for playing!</title>
    <link href="thank-you-player.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>


    <!-- ideal size for compassion forward logo, width="250" height="120" -->


        <div class="list"><br><br><br>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html"><span>Home</span></li>
          <li><a href="sponsor-form.php"><span>Sponsor</span></li>
          <li><a href="player-form.php"><span>Player</span></li>
          <li class="hide" style="display:none;"><a href="#"><span>Hidden</span></li>
        </ul>
        </div>

        <div style="display:none">
        The quick brown fox jumps over the head of the lazy dog.
        </div>


        <div class="info">

        <p><br><br><br>The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>



    <footer></footer>
</body>

</html>
```

If you could please take a look at the fiddle code for me.

Comment: You're missing the closing `a` tags - [here's your fiddle fixed up](https://jsfiddle.net/jen4owL5/).

Comment: check the below code i modified

Comment: Hey thanks! I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing `</a>`

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis&display=swap');
ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 8em;
  height: 2em;
  color: green;
  border-left: 0.08em solid;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0.8em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li::before,
li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit;
  border-left: inherit;
  z-index: -1;
}

li::before {
  height: 80%;
  top: 10%;
  left: calc(-0.15em - 0.08em * 2);
  filter: brightness(0.8);
}

li::after {
  height: 60%;
  top: 20%;
  left: calc(-0.15em * 2 - 0.08em * 3);
  filter: brightness(0.6);
}

li span {
  position: relative;
  height: 120%;
  top: -10%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 0.08em solid;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  transform: translateX(calc(-0.15em * 3 - 0.08em * 2));
  transition: 0.3s;
}

li:hover span {
  transform: translateX(0.15em);
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: green;
}

.list {
  float: right;
  margin: 15px 15px 15px 50px;
  max-width: 7%;
  position: relative;
}

.hide {
  /* */
  /*  text-decoration: none;
 list-style-type: none; */
}

.info {
  text-align: justify;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 1% 1% 1% 8%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  < !–– box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  ––>padding: 20px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 150%;
  font-family: font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
  border-radius: 15px;
  z-index: -1;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.golf_video {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.cf-logo-with-details {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  margin: 15px 15px 15px 10px;
  max-width: 15%;
}

.asurion_and_cf {
  float: left;
  margin: 15px 15px 15px 50px;
  max-width: 7%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="list"><br><br><br>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html"><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="sponsor-form.php"><span>Sponsor</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="player-form.php"><span>Player</span></a></li>
    <li class="hide" style="display:none;"><a href="#"><span>Hidden</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div style="display:none">
  The quick brown fox jumps over the head of the lazy dog.
</div>


<div class="info">

  <br><br><br>The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
  laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id
  est laborum." Section 1.10.32 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis
  et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum
  quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut
  aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
</div>
```

Comment: haha, your alright. Come back when you have reputations :D :D